# Dúvida na criação de aplicativo

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, apache-cordova, app

Estou criando um aplicativo para celular phonegap/cordova no qual necessito pesquisar o nome de um local, telefone e endereço e encontrar em um mapa. Estou em dúvida se utilizo o phonegap/cordova geolocation ou o API do google maps. E também como farei para ele localizar essas informações já que não possuo nenhuma noção de banco de dados apenas HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li sobre a api do google, parece que tem um certo limite de buscas/uso.
veja se a api do phonegap tem esse limite, caso não, a vantagem será essa do phonegap. claro, se não for suficiente o limite.

sobre um começo ao usar a api do google, gostei desses artigos:

http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-busca-de-endereco-e-autocomplete.html

http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-um-mapa-personalizado.html
usaria como experiência pra um projeto.

se for usar banco de dados, procure sobre:  LocalStorage. 
estou usando recentemente nos meus projetos e estou gostando.